# Windows Phone App needs to read in from xml source

Tags: c#, xml

Issues with trying to fill a list with values from an XML source.

I have a WebClient to read into the project which calls the function below.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
Uri url = new Uri("http://www.usi.edu/webservices/iphone/USIINFOterms.xml", UriKind.Absolute);
client.OpenReadAsync(url);
```

The function

```
public void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var xml = XDocument.Load(e.Result);

        var results = from row in xml.Element("value").Elements() select row;
        // now I loop all rows and print the title; of course you canfc
        // do other stuff here or combine some data processing with the LINQ above
        // - this is up to you
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            item.ItemLine1 = result.Value;
            list.Add(item);
         }
     }
     catch (Exception c)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(c.Message);
     }
}
```

The list elements return a null reference.

Here's what the XML file looks like

```
<data>
 <row>
  <value>Fall 2013</value> 
  <value>201410</value> 
 </row>
 <row>
  <value>Third Summer 2013</value> 
  <value>201350</value> 
 </row>
```

Not having too much luck with the xml file. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Replace `XDocument.Load(e.Result)` with `XDocument.Parse(e.Result)`. [XDocument.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx) treats is argument as a URI, and you have -- I assume -- already downloaded the XML document.  [XDocument.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx) cracks open that document for you.
2. Try the following:

   ```
   var results = from row in xml.Root.Elements("row")
                 select row.Element("value");
   ```

   [XElement.Elements()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.elements.aspx) only works from the current XML element -- it doesn't scan the entire XML document tree.  To scan the entire tree, you can use [XElement.Descendants()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx).  Or, to more precisely pick the elements you need, use the pattern as above -- pick elements from the first level, then go deeper into the next level.

Comment: This worked and got rid of the null reference error; however, the loop  that goes through the results seems to not be triggering.

Comment: Consider looking in the debugger at what is returned by parts of the Linq expression, e.g. what does xml.Root.Elements("row") return?  Also note that I replaced xml.Elements() in your code with xml.Root.Elements().

Comment: When printing out xml.Root.Elements("row") I get this:
The thread '<No Name>' (0xe3a004e) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xea1005a) has exited with code 0 (0x0).